# Checkboxes Dependent on Some Others

Tags: vba, checkbox

I'm trying to put together a spreadsheet, which has lots of options and sub-options. I'm using checkboxes, but I want to use VBA code which will just change some checkboxes but not all. For example:

Type Of Breakfast Required

Cooked

```
 Eggs
 Bacon
 Toast
```

Uncooked

```
  Cereal
  Fruit
```

What I want is code with which the user can first of all check or uncheck a checkbox for Cooked or Uncooked, which will in turn check or uncheck all of the relevant sub-options.

At the same time, I want to then be able to select/deselect sub-options, if for example someone wants a cooked breakfast but all they want is toast.

(This is not the application that my spreadsheet is being put to, but merely to show the structure required)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: THere's a number of ways, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried For each checkbox in... etc, but the problem is differentiating between the different sub groups I've also tried naming the checkboxes differently, such as Cooked1, Cooked2, Cooked3, Uncooked1, Uncooked2, but I can't work out how to select them by name or caption

Comment: `controls("Cooked" & x).value`

Comment: Thanks. I think I've got the first part now. I'm now trying to work out whether I need to use triplestate on the cooked option, to allow for the 'toast only' sub-option.

Comment: All sorted now. Thanks for your help.